# fabric JS not running on node after installing correctly

Tags: node.js, npm, fabricjs

I want to use fabric js on a node server to generate SVG images. I followed the instructions to run fabric js on node in a mac environment. I'm trying to run the hello world fabric application from the fabric js documentation under nodejs examples.

If i run `typeof require('canvas');` in the node shell. It returns 'function' as it should, according to fabricjs [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4) 
Running `typeof require('fabric');` also returns `object` as it should. Im pretty sure that I installed the dependencies correctly but not entirely sure why the code is not running as expected.

However, running the code results in this error: `TypeError: fabric.createCanvasForNode is not a function`

Here is the code I am trying to run.

I changed my python version to 2.7 and node is v 9.2.0 . All help is appreciated!

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/helloworld.png');

var canvas = fabric.createCanvasForNode(200, 200);

var text = new fabric.Text('Hello world', {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: '#f55',
  angle: 15
});
canvas.add(text);

var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
  out.write(chunk);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Dez' Answer almost satisfied me, but it was not a fully working example. At least not for me. This is my result after digging a little bit deeper into the topic:

```
const { fabric } = require("fabric");
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(null, {width: 500, height: 500});

const fs = require("fs");
const stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
const out = fs.createWriteStream("test.png");

var text = new fabric.Text("Hello world", {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: "#f55",
  angle: 15
});

canvas.add(text);

canvas.renderAll();

stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
  out.write(chunk);
});
```

Comment: Getting "Cannot read property 'imageSmoothingEnabled' of null at klass._setImageSmoothing "...

Comment: Which version of node-canvas are you using? Make sure to use 1.6.x, not 2.

Comment: I think it is 2. But most recent fabric.js requires node-canvas 2, doesn't it?

Comment: No, unfortunately it still requires you to use node-canvas 1.6.x. You can check the version by inspecting your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the problem you are getting I understand you are using a version over 2.0.0 and since said version it seems they have deprecated the method `createCanvasForNode`.
You could easily confirm that by evaluating the `fabric` import and see the method is not available anymore.

From now on you can use `fabric.Canvas` or `fabric.StaticCanvas`.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    fabric = require('fabric').fabric,
    out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/helloworld.png');

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(200, 200);
// or either var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(200, 200);

var text = new fabric.Text('Hello world', {
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: '#f55',
  angle: 15
});
canvas.add(text);

var stream = canvas.createPNGStream();
stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
  out.write(chunk);
});
```

Reference 1: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/3885

Reference 2: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/4586

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your response. Applying your changes got me inside of the function call, but failed at `fabric.js:6840
      this.contextContainer = this.lowerCanvasEl.getContext('2d');` `TypeError: this.lowerCanvasEl.getContext is not a function` Any idea why this could occur?

Comment: Maybe you should check out how to do things with the new library version and if still having problems, open a new question. You can't follow the same path if library has changed drastically.